# Navigation Drawer on old android Versions

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

since i have added a new activity (with Navigation drawer), i get error, when i call this activity :

```
 Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eu.study.myapp.tutorial/com.myapp.tutorial.welcome}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
```

i get no error on android 6.0, i get error on old versions like 4.1.2

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView   //error here at line 16
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_welcome"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_welcome_drawer" />
```

I have added these 2 things but the error not fixed :

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' 
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Comment: You could set the min version to the earliest version that supports it. See here https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html to view the percentage of users you can get to if choose a certain min version.

Comment: does android 4.1.2 not suport this navigation drawer ?